# how to show json data on tool tip message using boots strap tool tip

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>`enter code here`
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{"test":"123"}">Hover over me</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to show json data on tool tip I am using above code but getiin only { on tool tip.
please let me know to show the data as {"test":"123"} on tool tip using jquery and boots strap tool tip

Answer (score 0):

If you are using double quotes for a string, then use single quotes inside double quotes and if you are using single quotes for a string, then use double quotes inside single quotes.

Following are valid strings:

1. '{"test":"123"}'
2. "{'test':'123'}"

So following code will show required json data in tooltip:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title='{"test":"123"}' >Hover over me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in this line:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{"test":"123"}">Hover over me</a>
```

Change the inner quote with the escaped string **&quot;** (for more info see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity))

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{&quot;test&quot;:&quot;123&quot;}">Hover over me</a>
```

The snippet:

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{&quot;test&quot;:&quot;123&quot;}">Hover over me</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotations instead of double quotations like that:

`'{"test":"123"}'` instead of that: `"{"test":"123"}"`